# Session não fica nula, mas não logado

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Estou tentando autenticar uma página para que somente pessoa que esteja logada possa acessar uma página. Estou usando esse código.

```
if (Session["user"] == null)
            RedirectToAction("Login", "Usuario");
```

Porém mesmo não logado ele não entra nesse if, pelo que entendi é que a minha aplicação cria uma **SESSION**, por isso ela não é NULL

Comment: Fiz um teste aqui e funcionou. Você não preenche a session em outro lugar? Coloque o código dessa Action.

Comment: Só se minha aplicação faz isso por si só.

Comment: Isso acontece no debug? Já tentou colocar um log para ver o que tem na Session?